# python3.9 doesn't recognize Walrus operator :=

Tags: python, django

I created a virtual environment in python3.9.
Then I installed django 4.0 framework by pip command.
It's ok but surprise it seems python 3.9 doesn't recognize operator `:=`. This operator is been introduced in python 3.8. Why I get this error from django framework?
I can't modify all files for using a normal syntax! These files are many.

```
nicola@giustizia:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/myproj-error.log
[Fri Oct 21 16:18:48.196449 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 17067]   File "/home/nicola/webgiustizia/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
[Fri Oct 21 16:18:48.196452 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 17067]     from django import forms
[Fri Oct 21 16:18:48.196457 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 17067]   File "/home/nicola/webgiustizia/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
[Fri Oct 21 16:18:48.196461 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 17067]     from django.forms.fields import *  # NOQA
[Fri Oct 21 16:18:48.196475 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 17067]   File "/home/nicola/webgiustizia/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 43, in <module>
[Fri Oct 21 16:18:48.196479 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 17067]     from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime, parse_duration
[Fri Oct 21 16:18:48.196494 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 17067]   File "/home/nicola/webgiustizia/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 118
[Fri Oct 21 16:18:48.196501 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 17067]     if match := datetime_re.match(value):
[Fri Oct 21 16:18:48.196519 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 17067]               ^
[Fri Oct 21 16:18:48.196544 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 17067] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you sure the correct version of Python is interpreting those modules?

Comment: I don't sure How can I know if mod_wsgi is using python3.9 and not 3.6? please

Comment: One design principle underpinning the walrus operator is that there are no identical code contexts where both an assignment statement using the = operator and an assignment expression using the := operator would be valid. For example, you can’t do a plain assignment with the walrus operator,

In many cases, you can add parentheses (()) around the assignment expression to make it valid Python:

>>> (walrus := True)

Comment: Which version of mod_wsgi do you have installed?  Do you have a virtual env set up that is being used?  And if you run things with the development server does it work?

Comment: mod_wsgi is 4.5 version I have a virtual environment with python 3.9 installed in wsgi.conf I set WSGIPythonHome /home/nicola/webgiustizia

Comment: Please help me to understand what python version it used by mod_wsgi

Comment: I install libapache2-mod-wsgi3 but it work with 3.6. How can I set 3.9 interpreter?

Comment: You can't install it with apt compatible with py3.9, it was compiled for 3.6. Instead you can run something like `mod_wsgi-express install-module | tee /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi_express.load /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi_express.conf` and `a2enmod` that module. However, if you're using virtual environment, get ready to spend some time playing with configuration file to resolve path issues.